# import native node.js modules doesn't works

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In my angular4 service.ts i need some node.js packages like fs.

```
ng serve
```

crashes with

```
ERROR in C:/js/src/app/data.service.ts (2,21): Cannot find module 'fs'.

ERROR in multi script-loader!./~/fs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\js\node_modules\fs' in 'C:\js'
 @ multi script-loader!./~/fs
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

for my source line

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

within

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as fs from 'fs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor() {
   }
}
```

I use

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.3
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
```

It looks like that i configure something in .angular-cli.json, but where?

Any help needed. 
Many thanks.

Comment: fs is a node library for file handling , check your package.json file for such dependecies, or you can delete your node module altogether and do a npm install

Comment: no, this is not the solution, my package.json includes `@types/node` and `ts-node`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular CLI as you mentioned before, you need to add your node lib to it in order to be included and be available to be used.

How to? in the angular-cli.json file, like this:

```
    "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
```

> Have in mind that the path specified depends on your "**root**"
>   parameter specified on the angular-cli.json file.

Hope it helps.